# How to Use Angular UI Typeahead with Parse API?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, angular-ui

I want to implement Typeahead (Auto-complete) functionality by fetching results from remote database using Parse API, I have tried implementing it following manner, I am getting the JSON Array but am not able to show it as a dropdown...following is my code

**HTML**

```
<input type="text"
           ng-model="address.locality"
           placeholder="Locality"
           typeahead="locality for locality in getLocation($viewValue)"
           typeahead-min-length="3"
           typeahead-loading="isLoading"
           typeahead-no-results="noResults"
           class="form-control newAddressFields">
    <i ng-show="isLoading" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
    <div ng-show="noResults">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results Found
    </div>
```

**Controller**

```
    $scope.noResults = false;
    $scope.localities = [];
    $scope.isLoading = false;

$scope.getLocation = function(val) {

        var filteredSearch= val.toLowerCase();
        var city_lw = $scope.address.city.toLowerCase();
       /* console.log(filteredSearch)*/;
        var Mapping = Parse.Object.extend("COD_Area_List");

        var localityQuery = new Parse.Query(Mapping);


        localityQuery.startsWith("Locality_sm",filteredSearch);
        localityQuery.equalTo("city_sm", city_lw);
        $scope.localities = [];
        $scope.isLoading = true;
        localityQuery.find({
            success: function(results) {
                $scope.isLoading = false;
                 console.log("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " responses.");


                if(results.length > 0){
                    $scope.noResults = false;
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        var object = results[i].toJSON();
                        /*console.log(object);*/
                        $scope.localities.push(object.Locality);
                    }
                } else{
                    $scope.noResults = true;
                }
                console.log($scope.localities);
                //This has results showing but not in the dropdown below Typeahead
                return $scope.localities;

            },
            error: function(error) {
                // There was an error.
                $scope.isLoading = false;

            }

        });

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML you have used

`typeahead="locality for locality in getLocation($viewValue)"`

and in Controller $scope.localities you have an array containing Objects..
So you might view 'Object' in dropdown list..

Solution for your problem is use property of object in HTML..

Suppose your locality object looks like this = {city:"some_city",state:"some_state"}

So try this..

`typeahead="locality.city for locality in getLocation($viewValue)"`

Comment: its a plain simple array of results pls see                                                                           for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        var object = results[i].toJSON();
                        /*console.log(object);*/
                        $scope.localities.push(object.Locality);
                    }                         I am only pushing object.Locality which is a string